# Why does my Mii Fighter occasionally have the wrong moves?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Every once and a while, I'll select my Mii Fighter and all of the moves will be set to what I assume are the "default" moves. This usually means doing an Airborne Assault off the edge instead of throwing a Chakram and a lot of frustration. I can only assume this is a bug, but is there a way to avoid this bug? Does something in particular trigger it?

Comment: Last time I played, I wondered if the difference was whether "custom fighters" was turned on or off...

Comment: When you select a mii, there is a question mark option which will randomize your mii movesets (also appears for any character when custom moves are turned on), are you sure you are not sometimes selecting that?

Comment: @luisluix I remember seeing that for other fighters, but not Miis. I'll have to double check when I next play.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you put in the right moves for your fighter and make sure to save it. Your game should not be able to change the moves that you set for a Mii Fighter.